# In SpecFlow, should I use a class field or ScenarioContext for the object that I'm testing?

Tags: c#, specflow

I'm testing a class MortgageCalculator using SpecFlow. I've found that I have two ways of setting up my step file, one where I have a class level MortgageCalculator, and the other where I use ScenarioContext (see below). Which is better?

I find Option 1 to be much easier, because I don't have to keep getting and setting the ScenarioContext. But I've been taught to use ScenarioContext.

Option 1:

```
[Binding]
public sealed class MortgageCalculatorSteps
{
    private MortgageCalculator calculator;

    [Given(@"I have a MortgageCalculator")]
    public void GivenIHaveAMortgageCalculator()
    {
        calculator = new MortgageCalculator();
    }

    [Then(@"I can do something with the calculator")]
    public void ThenICanDoSomethingWithTheCalculator()
    {
        calculator.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

Option 2:

```
[Binding]
public sealed class MortgageCalculatorSteps
{
    [Given(@"I have a MortgageCalculator")]
    public void GivenIHaveAMortgageCalculator()
    {
        var calculator = new MortgageCalculator();
        ScenarioContext.Current.Set(calculator);
    }

    [Then(@"I can do something with the calculator")]
    public void ThenICanDoSomethingWithTheCalculator()
    {
        var calculator = ScenarioContext.Current.Get<MortgageCalcualtor>();
        calculator.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion neither of the options you have outlined are the best solution. As Andreas pointed out in the other answer the best option is to use [ContextInjection](http://www.specflow.org/documentation/Context-Injection/). Why?

- Works when the tests are run in parallel, which using `ScenarioContext.Current` won't
- Allows data to be shared between different classes containing steps, which in turn allows you yo organise your steps in any way you want and avoids having very large classes containing many step methods
- Allows your data to be strongly typed
- Allows your data to be collected in appropriate cohesive classes, each maintaining the Single Responsibility Principle

We tend to call these classes contexts, so My option in your situation would be to do this, probably:

```
[Binding]
public sealed class MortgageCalculatorSteps
{
    private MortgageCalculatorContext calculatorContext;

    public MortgageCalculatorSteps(MortgageCalculatorContext calculatorContext)
    {
        this.calculatorContext=calculatorContext;
    }

    [Given(@"I have a MortgageCalculator")]
    public void GivenIHaveAMortgageCalculator()
    {
        calculatorContext.Calculator = new MortgageCalculator();
        // or you could do something like: calculator.InitialiseCalculator()
    }

    [Then(@"I can do something with the calculator")]
    public void ThenICanDoSomethingWithTheCalculator()
    {
        calculatorContext.Calculator.DoSomething();
    }
}
```

the benefits may not be obvious in a simple example like this, but in my experience this makes your life a lot simpler in the long run.

Answer (score 2):

SpecFlow has a concept named Context Injection.
It is the preferred way of storing state during a test run of a scenario.
Have a look at the documentation here: http://www.specflow.org/documentation/Context-Injection/